# Overriding ToString when creating interface type using object expression

Tags: f#

Is there a way to override `System.Object`'s virtual methods, particularly `ToString`, when creating an interface type using an object expression?

```
type INamedObject =
    abstract Name : string

let makeNamedObject name = 
    { new INamedObject with
        member x.Name = name
        override x.ToString() = x.Name } //would like to do this, but doesn't work
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to supplly multiple types to implement / override in an object expression including concrete types.  This allows you to both specify `Object` and `INamedObject` in the expression and get the desired effect.

```
let makeNamedObject name =  
    { 
        new System.Object() with 
            member x.ToString() = name
        interface INamedObject with
            member x.Name = name  }
```